# Tooltips showing measure values for stacked area chart Tableau

Tags: data-visualization, tooltip, tableau-api, dashboard

I am new to Tableau, but am working to learn how to use it for dashboards. I have created a stacked area chart containing both durable goods and non-durable goods across time. Currently I can't fix the tooltip from showing both values of a date, it will only give the value for the item I am hovering over. How can I edit the tooltip to show both at once? I have attached a screenshot below:

[Tableau chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKxH0.png)

Comment: I would also appreciate help to show the relative % of the total for each value. If it helps, I have a value for the total sum of the two

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "show both at once".     Could you type out what you want the tool tip to look like when you hover over the upper line and when you hover over the lower line?

Comment: Month of Date: <MONTH(Date)>
Durable Goods:  <Measure Values>      #make this one show durable goods value
Non Durable Goods: <Measure Values> #make this one show non durable goods value

Comment: Not quite, I would like to include both measure names' values for that time-stamp wherever my cursor is.

Comment: So the image you posted is what you WANT?   I thought it was what you currently got and did NOT want.  So one more time:   Tableau default seems to be to just show one value in a stacked graph for each date ( the value for the segment you are hovering over ) ,   and apparently you do NOT want that.  So what you DO want would be:  on line one of the tool-tip;  "Month of Date   November 2020".  On line 2 of the tool-tip "Durable Goods    $2000  40%" and on line 3 of the tool-tip "Non-Durable Goods  $3000 60%".    And that would be exactly the same regardless where your cursor was vertically?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show more than just the default measure in a tooltip, make your stacked chart then drag the measures you want to see into the "Tooltip" box on the Marks card. They should show up just below that box.  Then click the "tooltip" box and set up your lable text. In your case:

```
Month of Date:  
Durable Goods:  
Non-Durable Goods:
```

Then in turn click to the right of each label,  select the INSERT option at the upper right of the tooltip-editing-window, and select the relevant item, and it should then appear in place surrounded by "<  >"  brackets.

So you would end up with a tooltip looking something like this

```
Month of Date:      <Month(Date)>
Durable Goods:      <SUM(Durable Goods>
Non-Durable Goods:  <SUM(Non-Durable Goods)>
```

You can click PREVIEW to confirm that much works. Exit the editor.
Then create your computed fields,  say "DG%" and "NDG%".
Probaby something like DG% = FLOOR ( 100 * SUM([Durable Goods]) / (SUM([Durable-goods]) + SUM ([NonDurable-Goods])  )

Maybe you should use ROUND instead of FLOOR because FLOOR isn't defined for some data sources but I think ROUND is always defined.

Drag each of THOSE onto the ToolTip little box in the Marks Card.
As you do that they should show up in the Marks Card as "AGG(DG%), etc.

Then double-click the tooltip box to pop up the tooltip editor, and they should show up when you click INSERT  and you can insert them in the tooltip and possibly surround them with "(" and   "%)"

Voila.

Wade

Comment: Cheers! Thank you Wade. Great help and easy to follow directions.